# Convert data.frame to matrix in order to set 2 dimensions

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a matrix out of a dataframe to obtain the sum of two combined attributes :

This is my dataframe :

groupbyDf :

```
> x1 y1 5
> x2 y1 6
> x2 y2 3
> x3 y1 4
> ...
```

I woud like to convert this into a matrix like this :

matrixXY :

```
>    y1 y2
> x1 5  0
> x2 6  3
> x3 4  0
```

I have previously grouped by my first dataframe this way :

```
> groupbyDf <-Df %>%
>  filter (----) %>%
>  select (x, y) %>%
>  group_by(x, y) %>%
>  summarize(n())
```

In order to further create plot with x as abscissa and y as ordonate

I also can't rename the n() column created by my group_by.

Hope it is understandable
Thank you !

Comment: looks like you need `tidyr::spread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make “matrixXY”, if your data frame is “groupbyDf”, with 2nd columned names “y” and 3rd column named “z”, try:

```
spread(groupbyDf, key = y, value = z, fill = 0)
```

I’m not sure what you mean by you “can’t” rename n in your summarize: you’re trying to but haven’t been able to, or you need to leave it that name.

If it’s the former, just name it in the call to summarize:

```
summarize(desiredName = n())
```